# MS Report Builder: have 2 columns in one report reference the same value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I'm new to stackoverflow, well, as a writer. You folks here have helped me out in so many sitations already, and now I have a question that I don't even know how to properly formulate so it's hard to google it, but I'm confident someone on here knows what I mean and can actually help me quite easily - fingers crossed. I'm sure the answer is super easy, but my head is just blocked right now.

So, I have an SQL report that's basically about shipping goods in and out. In the database, there's, for example, t1 which contains the columns id_shipper_in and id_shipper_out. Then there's t2, which contains info about the shippers, name, contacts etc. This table has only one id for all shippers, of course, as they can be at various times shipping goods in OR out, so we have id_shipper and name_shipper in this table.

Now, how do I write a nice little query so I have a table that displays the actual NAME of the shipper instead of id_shipper_in and id_shipper_out? So it's, e.g.

DATE IN    | GOODS | NAME SHIPPER IN | DATE OUT    | NAME SHIPPER OUT |

07/07/2022 | Cars  | DHL             | 08/07/2022  | UPS              |

Again, I'm sorry, this is probably heartbreakingly easy, but I just can't see it right now.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It is a good practice to provide some  sample data, expected result, your attempts to solve the problem and platform you are working on. You can find more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I understand the question and so are the others. Someone will ansewer it pretty soon, just keep in mind for the future to put all the needed info into next post.

Answer (score 0):

WITH clause is here just to generate some sample data and, as such, it is not a part of the answer.
You should your trafic table join with table containing IDs and Names **twice.** In one case join key is ID_IN and in another join key is ID_OUT.
This way you can get both names at the same time. Note the aliases of the tables - joining the same table twice makes it important to name the joins differently so you could manipulate the data you are selecting. Hope this will solve your problem. Regards...

```sql
WITH
    table_trafic AS
        (
            Select 10 "ID_IN", '2022-02-04' "DATE_IN", 14 "ID_OUT", '2022-02-06' "DATE_OUT", 'Cars' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 20 "ID_IN", '2022-03-14' "DATE_IN", 30 "ID_OUT", '2022-03-15' "DATE_OUT", 'Computers' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 10 "ID_IN", '2022-04-01' "DATE_IN", 12 "ID_OUT", '2022-04-12' "DATE_OUT", 'Apliences' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 14 "ID_IN", '2022-05-04' "DATE_IN", 20 "ID_OUT", '2022-05-07' "DATE_OUT", 'Tools' "GOODS" From Dual
        ),
    table_shippers AS
        (
            Select 10 "SHIPPER_ID", 'DHL' "SHIPPER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 12 "SHIPPER_ID", 'GLS' "SHIPPER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 14 "SHIPPER_ID", 'OVERSEAS' "SHIPPER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 20 "SHIPPER_ID", 'UPS' "SHIPPER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 30 "SHIPPER_ID", 'FARGO' "SHIPPER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 40 "SHIPPER_ID", 'WESTERN'" SHIPPER_NAME" From Dual 
        )
--  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
    tt.DATE_IN "DATE_IN",
    tt.GOODS "GOODS",
    t_in.SHIPPER_NAME "NAME_SHIPPER_IN",
    tt.DATE_OUT "DATE_OUT",
    t_out.SHIPPER_NAME "NAME_SHIPPER_OUT"
FROM
    table_trafic tt
INNER JOIN
    table_shippers t_in ON(t_in.SHIPPER_ID = tt.ID_IN)
INNER JOIN
    table_shippers t_out ON(t_out.SHIPPER_ID = tt.ID_OUT)
--
--  R e s u l t
--
--      DATE_IN    GOODS     NAME_SHIPPER_IN DATE_OUT   NAME_SHIPPER_OUT
--      ---------- --------- --------------- ---------- ----------------
--      2022-04-01 Apliences DHL             2022-04-12 GLS              
--      2022-02-04 Cars      DHL             2022-02-06 OVERSEAS         
--      2022-05-04 Tools     OVERSEAS        2022-05-07 UPS              
--      2022-03-14 Computers UPS             2022-03-15 FARGO
```

You can add Where clause to select data you want and Order By clause to order them the way that suits you the best...